# Android DDMS Loaded GPX file Pausing Itself

Tags: android, android-emulator, gpx

I am loading a GPX file into my emulator.

**THE PROBLEM**

The file has 7226 points (it says so in the Point Count column) so the file is being loaded in correctly. However, the problem happens when I press the play button it only reads in about 4 points before it then pauses itself. This is not the functionality I want.

**THE QUESTION**

How do I make it run through the entire file without it pausing itself?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake of answering the question from my research and for those of you looking for a solution yourself.

I couldn't manage to get the entire GPX file loaded in via the `DDMS` even when using different types of converters that you can find online.

The solution in the end was to have a set of classes which decode a GPX file into a set of locations and then do whatever you want with those.

I hope this helps even it is just confirming your thoughts that it wont work (well i couldn't work it out!) :)